# c# save trackbar.value

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I'm trying to save a `TrackBar` value to a variable but can't manage to do it since the value changed all the time.

```
void VolumeBarScroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    int a = VolumeBar.Value;

     }
```

Is there any way of keeping a value?.

Comment: Where do you want to use the value? In the same class, declare a class level var for it.

Comment: move a variable outside method

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set value instantly - use `ValueChanged` event.
If you need to set value only once after finish changing - use `MouseCaptureChanged` event.

`Scroll` event - it's behaviour event.

> *Occurs when either a mouse or keyboard action moves the scroll box.*

So, probably you need:

```
    int trackValue = 0;
    private void trackBar1_MouseCaptureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackValue = this.trackBar1.Value;
    }
```

Also, you are trying to save value to a local variable inside of event handler, if you need to use it outside of event handler, you need to define variable outside of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look to this blogs...

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/348366

http://en.csharp-online.net/TrackBar